# Using Linq instead of foreach

Tags: c#, xml

I want to load some configs from an external app.config (appSettings) from another project, the loaded values must be saved in some of my properties. Here (see comments in code) is what I want to do:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = MyXmlDocument;
if (xmlDoc != null)
{
    XmlNodeList appSettings = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/configuration/appSettings/add");
    if (appSettings != null && appSettings.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (XmlNode node in appSettings)
        {
            XmlAttribute keyAttr = node.Attributes["key"];
            if (keyAttr != null)
            {
                if (keyAttr.Value == "MyProperty1NameInConfigFile") MyProperty1 = node.Attributes["value"].Value; 
                // ....
            }
        }


        // Instead of using foreach loop, I want to use Linq like this:
        var node = get me the node that has the keyAttribute.Value == "MyProperty1NameInConfigFile"
        MyProperty1 = node.Attributes["value"].Value; 

        // If I got this, then I can later use another method for each property like this:
        SaveConfigToMyProperty(ref MyProperty1, "MyProperty1NameInConfigFile");
        SaveConfigToMyProperty(ref MyProperty2, "MyProperty2NameInConfigFile");
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to use XML readers to use app.config?

Comment: because I'm using an app.config of another project. I want to read the settings from an external app.config.

Comment: Might want to add that tidbit to the question so people (like me) don't browbeat you over it. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cast your `XmlDocument` to an `IEnumerable<XmlNode>` you can get all the fun LINQ queries. After that you can grab whatever you like. Maybe something like this?

```
var node = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/configuration/appSettings/add").Cast<XmlNode>()
  .Where(n => n.Attributes["key"].Value == "MyProperty1NameInConfigFile");
```

Comment: Gah, beat me to it >_<

Comment: Thanks Lily, adding .FirstOrDefault(); at the end of your query will fix a compile error. Worked fine.

Comment: If you want to use Linq with XML, then it's better to use XElement as opposed to XmlDocument

Answer (score 0):

Here's an XElement solution, more geared toward working with Linq;

```
string xml = "";//xml as string;
var txtReader = new XmlTextReader(xml, XmlNodeType.Element);
var root = XElement.Load( txtReader );

var node = root.XPathSelectElements("/configuration/appSettings/add")
                .FirstOrDefault(n => 
                    n.Attributes["key"] != null && 
                    n.Attributes["key"].Value == "MyProperty1NameInConfigFile");
```

Comment: Ok, but what are the benefits of using XElement instead of using XmlDocument?

Comment: Well, you don't have to apply an unnecessary cast in order to use the Linq library. For more info see this; http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codejunkie/archive/2008/10/08/xmldocument-vs-xelement-performance.aspx